# Which is the best method for Paypal Recurring/Subscription?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am implementing papyal with php and I found that there are some different methods available to integrate Paypal Recurring/Subscription.

My account and requirement details are following:

- Merchant Account is of US/Canada,
- Dont want to pay any amount,
- Can cancel activate profile by code (not depend on user to click on unsubscribe button),

Which is the simple and best method?

1) NVP(Name Value Pair) API - It is deprecated, do not want to use.

2) Billing & Agreement API - It told me 'DPRP is disabled' and for enable it dont want to pay monthly $30 for Credit card payment.

3) Payflow - It asks me to complete profile and charge $10 for enable Recurring feature.

4) Subscription Button - Can I integrate it with checkout.js like Incontext Integration?

Please help me which should i prefer in my case ?

Comment: I'm wondering the same myself. I implemented the Billing Agreement method but I would like to use the new express cehckout api method that allows users to remain on my site during the checkout process but I cannot seem to find any info on how to set up recurring payments using the new express checkout api.

Comment: ok then which method are you using now?

Comment: I'm using the Billing Plan/Billing Agreement method right now. But I would like a solution that doesn't require my users to leave my website to subscribe. Something like the express checkout api but I still can't figure out how to do recurring payments through that api.

Comment: Can you able to create recurring payment via Credit Card directly? If yes, Did you enable Payment Pro feature on your merchant account?